# How to change chart font color

Tags: javascript, css, animation, charts, fonts

Okay all, I am simply trying to change the font color of my chart to a simple yellow color. This is for a school assignment, and I am having a hell of a time trying to figure it out. Any help at all would be appreciated.

I would use JsFiddle to display my code, but trying to use it with my code is just giving me a slough of errors, so I am simply going to post it here. I apologize in advanced to those of you who are actually willing to grit your teeth and read through it all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Unsolved Crimes Since Batman Appeared in Gothom</title>
<style>
#graph {
/* outline our canvas */
border:1px solid #03F;
}
</style>
<link href="bar_graph.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
// Canvas and drawing context variables
var canvas;
var context;
// Chart settings
var chartMargin;
var chartAxisSpace;
var chartWidth;
var chartHeight;
// bar variables
var numBars = 0; // total number of bars
var barMargin = 20; // margin between bars
var barWidth = 0; // bar width
var maxValue = 0; // maximum data value for the bars
// number of y-axis labels
var numYLabels;
// bar animation variables
var idxStep;
var numSteps;
var growSpeed;
// Chart JSON sample data
var chartData = {'bars':[
{'title':'Year 1','value':'156'},
{'title':'Year 2','value':'93'},
{'title':'Year 3','value':'55'},
{'title':'Year 4','value':'33'},
{'title':'Year 5','value':'20'},
{'title':'Year 6','value':'12'},
{'title':'Year 7','value':'7'},
]};

// initialize the board width and height
function initGraph() {
// get reference to canvas and drawing context
canvas = document.getElementById('graph');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
initSettings(); // initialize the chart settings
drawAxis(); // draw the chart axis and labels
growBars(); // animate the bars into the chart
}

function initSettings() {
// set our chart settings
chartMargin = 20; // margin around entire canvas
chartAxisSpace = 50; // area for the x- and y-axes
// set the chart drawing area
chartHeight = canvas.height-chartAxisSpace-2*chartMargin;
chartWidth = canvas.width-chartAxisSpace-2*chartMargin;
// set the number of labels to use for the y-axis
numYLabels = 7;
// set the number of bars based on the chartData
numBars = chartData.bars.length;
// find our max data value to scale the graph
for (var i=0; i < numBars; i++) {
if (chartData.bars[i].value > maxValue) {
maxValue = parseInt(chartData.bars[i].value);
}
}
// determine the width of each bar
barWidth = (chartWidth / numBars)-barMargin;
// initialize animation variables
idxStep = 0;
numSteps = 100;
growSpeed = 10;
}
function drawAxis() {
// Set line width for the axis lines
context.lineWidth = 2;
// draw y-axis - from lower left to upper left
context.moveTo(chartMargin+chartAxisSpace,chartHeight+chartMargin);
context.lineTo(chartMargin+chartAxisSpace, chartMargin);
context.stroke();
// draw X axis - from lower left to lower right
context.moveTo(chartMargin+chartAxisSpace, chartMargin+chartHeight);
context.lineTo(chartMargin+chartAxisSpace+chartWidth,
chartMargin+chartHeight);
context.stroke();
// Set the line width back to 1 pixel
context.lineWidth = 1;
// Add data marks to the y-axis
var markerAmount = parseInt(maxValue / numYLabels);
context.textAlign = 'right';
context.fillStyle = '#000';
// Loop through and add the markers to the y-axis
for (var i=0; i <= numYLabels; i++) {
// Determine the label and X and Y points
markerLabel = i*markerAmount;
markerXPos = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace - 5;
markerYPos = chartMargin + (chartHeight -
((i*markerAmount*chartHeight)/maxValue));
// Add the text marker at the positions determined
context.fillText(markerLabel, markerXPos, markerYPos, chartAxisSpace);
}
// Add labels for each bar based on the chart data
context.textAlign = 'center';
// loop through each bar and add the title
for (var i=0; i<numBars; i++) {
// determine the X and Y positions for the marker
markerXPos = chartMargin+chartAxisSpace + barMargin + (i *
(barWidth+barMargin)) + (.5*barWidth);
markerYPos = chartMargin+chartHeight + 10;
// Add the text under the bottom of the bar
context.fillText(chartData.bars[i].title, markerXPos, markerYPos,
barWidth);
}
// Add y-axis title
// Save the present context
context.save();
// Move the 0,0 point to the y-axis title point
context.translate(chartMargin+10,chartHeight/2);
// Rotate the current drawing context counter-clockwise 90 degrees
context.rotate(Math.PI*-90 / 180);
// Add our text title
context.fillText('Sales (in 000s)',0,0);
// Restore the context drawing orientation
context.restore();
// Add X Axis Title
context.fillText('Year Out',chartMargin+chartAxisSpace
(chartWidth/2),chartMargin+chartHeight+40);
}
// Animation function to grow the bars vertically
// Called on a timeout based on number of steps
function growBars() {
// Declare our bar x,y, and h
// barWidth is predetermined above
var barStartX = 0;
var barStartY = 0;
var barHeight = 0;
// bar value variable from the data set
var barValue = 0;
// Loop through the bars and draw each based on step
for (var i=0; i < numBars; i++) {
// get the bar value
barValue = parseInt(chartData.bars[i].value);
// calculate the bar height, starting x and y points
barHeight = (barValue * chartHeight / maxValue) / numSteps * idxStep;
barStartX = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace + (i * (barWidth + barMargin))
+ barMargin;
barStartY = chartMargin + (chartHeight-barHeight);
// call the helper function to draw the bar
drawBar(barStartX, barStartY, barWidth, barHeight);
}
// Grow the bars more if they have not finished growing
if (idxStep<numSteps) {
idxStep++;
setTimeout('growBars()',growSpeed);
}
}
// helper function to draw a bar based on dimensions passed
//could pass in context along with other params to customize
function drawBar(barX, barY, barW, barH) {
// Create rectangle with fill
context.fillStyle = '#000000';
context.fillRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
// Add shadow to bar
context.shadowOffsetX = 3;
context.shadowOffsetY = -3;
context.shadowBlur = 3;
context.shadowColor = 'rgba(200, 200, 200, .3)';
// Add line border on the bar
context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
}
// on page load initialize the bar chart
window.addEventListener('load',initGraph,false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Unsolved Crimes Since Batman Appeared in Gothom</h1>
<canvas id="graph" width="600" height="400">
This browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
</body>
<footer>
<a id="bck_btn" href="index.html"> Go Back</a>
</footer>
</html>
```

Now for those of you who actually are willing to help me, I have attached a picture to help identify which fonts I need to have the colors changed. [image: Graph with text that needs font color changed circled.] Now again, I do appreciate all of your help, so let me say thank you in advanced!

-Dark_nemesis

Comment: Did you not try fixing that "*slough of errors*"? Did you try pasting the code into [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/) to see what the errors were? Incidentally, pasting your code into both JS Hint and JS Fiddle ([repro](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/etr8nw2t/)) report no errors (though admittedly your chart doesn't show up, either), so what errors were you seeing?

Comment: @DavidThomas The errors that I was getting were about using javascript in the html box, and vice versa. There were not any errors pertaining to the code itself, and seeing as how the length of the code itself is pretty long, trying to separate the two seems a bit tedious right now. I am sorry for my laziness. It has just been a long day already, and just thinking about separating the javascript from the html is giving me a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add:

```
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
```

Here's the code

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Unsolved Crimes Since Batman Appeared in Gothom</title>
    <style>
      #graph {
        /* outline our canvas */
        border: 1px solid #03F;
      }

    </style>
    <link href="bar_graph.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script>
      // Canvas and drawing context variables
      var canvas;
      var context;
      // Chart settings
      var chartMargin;
      var chartAxisSpace;
      var chartWidth;
      var chartHeight;
      // bar variables
      var numBars = 0; // total number of bars
      var barMargin = 20; // margin between bars
      var barWidth = 0; // bar width
      var maxValue = 0; // maximum data value for the bars
      // number of y-axis labels
      var numYLabels;
      // bar animation variables
      var idxStep;
      var numSteps;
      var growSpeed;
      // Chart JSON sample data
      var chartData = {
        'bars': [{
          'title': 'Year 1',
          'value': '156'
        }, {
          'title': 'Year 2',
          'value': '93'
        }, {
          'title': 'Year 3',
          'value': '55'
        }, {
          'title': 'Year 4',
          'value': '33'
        }, {
          'title': 'Year 5',
          'value': '20'
        }, {
          'title': 'Year 6',
          'value': '12'
        }, {
          'title': 'Year 7',
          'value': '7'
        }, ]
      };

      // initialize the board width and height
      function initGraph() {
        // get reference to canvas and drawing context
        canvas = document.getElementById('graph');
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        initSettings(); // initialize the chart settings
        drawAxis(); // draw the chart axis and labels
        growBars(); // animate the bars into the chart
      }

      function initSettings() {
        // set our chart settings
        chartMargin = 20; // margin around entire canvas
        chartAxisSpace = 50; // area for the x- and y-axes
        // set the chart drawing area
        chartHeight = canvas.height - chartAxisSpace - 2 * chartMargin;
        chartWidth = canvas.width - chartAxisSpace - 2 * chartMargin;
        // set the number of labels to use for the y-axis
        numYLabels = 7;
        // set the number of bars based on the chartData
        numBars = chartData.bars.length;
        // find our max data value to scale the graph
        for (var i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
          if (chartData.bars[i].value > maxValue) {
            maxValue = parseInt(chartData.bars[i].value);
          }
        }
        // determine the width of each bar
        barWidth = (chartWidth / numBars) - barMargin;
        // initialize animation variables
        idxStep = 0;
        numSteps = 100;
        growSpeed = 10;
      }

      function drawAxis() {
        // Set line width for the axis lines
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        // draw y-axis - from lower left to upper left
        context.moveTo(chartMargin + chartAxisSpace, chartHeight + chartMargin);
        context.lineTo(chartMargin + chartAxisSpace, chartMargin);
        context.stroke();
        // draw X axis - from lower left to lower right
        context.moveTo(chartMargin + chartAxisSpace, chartMargin + chartHeight);
        context.lineTo(chartMargin + chartAxisSpace + chartWidth,
          chartMargin + chartHeight);
        context.stroke();
        // Set the line width back to 1 pixel
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        // Add data marks to the y-axis
        var markerAmount = parseInt(maxValue / numYLabels);
        context.textAlign = 'right';
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        // Loop through and add the markers to the y-axis
        for (var i = 0; i <= numYLabels; i++) {
          // Determine the label and X and Y points
          markerLabel = i * markerAmount;
          markerXPos = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace - 5;
          markerYPos = chartMargin + (chartHeight -
            ((i * markerAmount * chartHeight) / maxValue));

          // apply color
          context.fillStyle = 'yellow';

          // Add the text marker at the positions determined
          context.fillText(markerLabel, markerXPos, markerYPos, chartAxisSpace);
        }
        // Add labels for each bar based on the chart data
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        // loop through each bar and add the title
        for (var i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
          // determine the X and Y positions for the marker
          markerXPos = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace + barMargin + (i *
            (barWidth + barMargin)) + (.5 * barWidth);
          markerYPos = chartMargin + chartHeight + 10;
          // Add the text under the bottom of the bar
          context.fillText(chartData.bars[i].title, markerXPos, markerYPos,
            barWidth);
        }
        // Add y-axis title
        // Save the present context
        context.save();
        // Move the 0,0 point to the y-axis title point
        context.translate(chartMargin + 10, chartHeight / 2);
        // Rotate the current drawing context counter-clockwise 90 degrees
        context.rotate(Math.PI * -90 / 180);
        // Add our text title
        context.fillText('Sales (in 000s)', 0, 0);
        // Restore the context drawing orientation
        context.restore();
        // Add X Axis Title
        context.fillText('Year Out', chartMargin + chartAxisSpace(chartWidth / 2), chartMargin + chartHeight + 40);
      }
      // Animation function to grow the bars vertically
      // Called on a timeout based on number of steps
      function growBars() {
        // Declare our bar x,y, and h
        // barWidth is predetermined above
        var barStartX = 0;
        var barStartY = 0;
        var barHeight = 0;
        // bar value variable from the data set
        var barValue = 0;
        // Loop through the bars and draw each based on step
        for (var i = 0; i < numBars; i++) {
          // get the bar value
          barValue = parseInt(chartData.bars[i].value);
          // calculate the bar height, starting x and y points
          barHeight = (barValue * chartHeight / maxValue) / numSteps * idxStep;
          barStartX = chartMargin + chartAxisSpace + (i * (barWidth + barMargin)) + barMargin;
          barStartY = chartMargin + (chartHeight - barHeight);
          // call the helper function to draw the bar
          drawBar(barStartX, barStartY, barWidth, barHeight);
        }
        // Grow the bars more if they have not finished growing
        if (idxStep < numSteps) {
          idxStep++;
          setTimeout('growBars()', growSpeed);
        }
      }
      // helper function to draw a bar based on dimensions passed
      //could pass in context along with other params to customize
      function drawBar(barX, barY, barW, barH) {
        // Create rectangle with fill
        context.fillStyle = '#000000';
        context.fillRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
        // Add shadow to bar
        context.shadowOffsetX = 3;
        context.shadowOffsetY = -3;
        context.shadowBlur = 3;
        context.shadowColor = 'rgba(200, 200, 200, .3)';
        // Add line border on the bar
        context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeRect(barX, barY, barW, barH);
      }
      // on page load initialize the bar chart
      window.addEventListener('load', initGraph, false);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Unsolved Crimes Since Batman Appeared in Gothom</h1>
    <canvas id="graph" width="600" height="400">
      This browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
  </body>
  <footer>
    <a id="bck_btn" href="index.html"> Go Back</a>
  </footer>

</html>
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wdL5e2wz/

Comment: I actually just saw the context.fillStyle line in my code and just took a shot and changed the value to yellow. Just after I did that, I came here to let everyone know that I figured it out, but you had posted already. So thank you for your help! Now for a second question, how would I change the font size of just the titles? For example the "years out" and the "sales (in 000)".

Comment: @dark_nemesis you can use `context.font = ('normal 40pt Calibri');` check out more methods in this site: 
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-font-size/
and here's  the fiddle for the font size
https://jsfiddle.net/wdL5e2wz/2/